# Parsing URL parameters in eLUA

Tags: parsing, url, lua, gsub

Let's say I have an URL like: http://ip/rgb/color?R=200&G=100&B=300

How would I get the values of R, G and B into seperate variables? I've looked into g.sub but I still dont get it at all, the explanations were just code with no further words on how anything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string.match and patterns:

```
local url = "http://ip/rgb/color?R=200&G=100&B=300"
local r,g,b= url:match("R=(%d+)&G=(%d+)&B=(%d+)")
print (r,g,b)
```

Comment: This is the simplest way to go. But what does the %d+ do? Also how does lua know which value goes into which variable?

Comment: %d+  - means one or more digits, and variables get symbols between () into r,g,b by order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general solution that stores the fields and values in a table without having to know the names or the order of the fields:

```
S=[[
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjGpbabuLDTAhUD5iYKHe2LAzcQFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eluaproject.net%2F&usg=AFQjCNHWegTT2pHkN8L75iW2UZBA5_pOMQ&sig2=VxlaLWBWD81Hp8KF8ijw1Q
]]

t = {}
S = S:match(".-?(.*)$") .. "&"
for k,v in S:gmatch("(.-)=(.-)&") do
    t[k]=v
    print(k,v)
end
```

It first gets the list of arguments (everything after the first `?`), adding `&` at the end for uniformity. Then all key-value pairs are of the form *key*`=`*value*`&`.

Applying this code to your URL, you'll get `t.R`, `t.G`, `t.B`.